# Secret key in Authorization header vs. inside POST body

Tags: authorization

We have a few in house endpoint that we'd like to keep in house and be used by developers who have access to different servers.  We were going to generate a secret key, save the key on the respective servers, and then add it to the cURL request in the Authorization:Bearer header such as:

curl -H  "Authorization:Bearer some-token" https://www.some-endpoint.com

to be then verified when the endpoint was hit.

After doing some googling around, I noticed that Stripe uses:

curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers -u sk_some_secret_key -d amount=some_amount -d currency=usd -d destination=some_account

so that the key isn't sent as part of the header.  From a security standpoint, is one method more secure than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both requests are actually quite similar.  In either case, the authentication credentials end up in the HTTP request header.  You can see this by using the `--verbose` option with `curl`.

For the first case:

```
curl --verbose -H "Authorization:Bearer some-token" https://www.somesite.com/
```

From the verbose output, you can see that curl includes a header with the name `Authorization` and the value `Bearer some-token` in the request header:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.somesite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization:Bearer some-token
```

The second case uses [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

```
curl --verbose https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers -u sk_some_secret_key -d amount=some_amount -d currency=usd -d destination=some_account
```

curl prompts for the password to use for HTTP Basic Authentication.  Then, from the verbose output, you can see that curl includes a header with the name `authorization` and the value `Basic c2tfc29tZV9zZWNyZXRfa2V5OnRlc3Q=` in the request header:

```
> POST /v1/transfers HTTP/2
> Host: api.stripe.com
> authorization: Basic c2tfc29tZV9zZWNyZXRfa2V5OnRlc3Q=
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> content-length: 56
> content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

`c2tfc29tZV9zZWNyZXRfa2V5OnRlc3Q=` is the encoded username and password used for HTTP Basic Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

From the security standpoint these ways are about the same:

- in both cases the secret is protected by HTTPS, i.e. no matter of HTTP header or body
- in both cases the secret is visible on the command line, i.e. can be retrieved by an attacker from a leaked script or similar